# Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Has a callback don't know why this isn't working...I have working user system in place and I essentially just copied that system. Don't know why one works and the other doesn't. I've omitted the irrelevant code and included the jobs in the users model file out of laziness.

Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
It looks like this line app.post('/postjob', jobs.createJob); triggers the error.

```
[index.js]
mongoose.connect(uri);
require('./models/users_model.js');
require('./routes/routes.js')(app);

[routes.js]
module.exports = function(app){

    var jobs = require('../controllers/jobs_controller.js');

    app.all('/postjob', function(req, res){
        if (typeof req.session !== 'undefined' && req.session.user) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        res.render('pages/login', {msg:req.session.msg});
    });

    app.post('/postjob', jobs.createJob);
}



[jobs_controller.js]
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Job = mongoose.model('Job');

module.exports = function(app){

    exports.createJob = function(req, res){

        var job = new Job({created: Date.now});
        job.set('title', req.body.title);
        job.set('description', req.body.description);
        job.set('hours', req.body.hours);
        job.save(function(err){
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
            else {
                alert('Job Posted Succesfully');
            }
        });

    }

};

[users_models.js]
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: String,
    color: String,
    hashed_password: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var JobSchema = new Schema ({
    created: Date,
    postedBy: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    hours: String,
    applicants: String,
    closed: Date
});

mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);
```

Comment: Please provide also the error you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem exists in your `jobs_controller.js`. Try replacing the below code

```
module.exports = function(app){

    exports.createJob = function(req, res){

        var job = new Job({created: Date.now});
        job.set('title', req.body.title);
        job.set('description', req.body.description);
        job.set('hours', req.body.hours);
        job.save(function(err){
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
            else {
                alert('Job Posted Succesfully');
            }
        });

    }

};
```

with

```
exports.createJob = function(req, res){

        var job = new Job({created: Date.now});
        job.set('title', req.body.title);
        job.set('description', req.body.description);
        job.set('hours', req.body.hours);
        job.save(function(err){
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
            else {
                alert('Job Posted Succesfully');
            }
        });

    };
```

and also make sure you are sending the response instead of putting alert.

Comment: Thank you Rudra it now compiles and loads to localhost..I will have to test functionality in the days to come.