# npm start throws error in Webstorm

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First of all, I'm new to MEAN in this case Node so I hope I will not irritate anybody by a possible lack of information concerning the error I receive.

My application did work without any problems till yesterday, after restarting Webstorm and reconnecting to my MongoDB first, to then start node I received these errors in the Terminal. I did not change a single file, it randomly started to throw out these errors, so since I'm a newbie I would appreciate any clues or suggestions what to look into to solve this mess.

```
Jake-MBP:test jake$ npm start

> test@0.0.0 start /Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test
> node ./bin/www

/Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196
    throw new Error(msg);
    ^

Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
at Route.(anonymous function) [as post] (/Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196:15)
at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as post] (/Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:510:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test/models/survey.js:7:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test/controllers/surveysController.js:1:63)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! test@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jake/WebstormProjects/test/npm-debug.log
```

As mentioned above, I did not change anything prior to this error.

Comment: You are supposed to pass a function to Route.post but you posted a object. Check this posting at  [Route.post() requires callback functions but got a Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413396/error-route-post-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This is strange since I followed the instructions step by step concerning the model and controller causing this error. I did manage from your post to isolate the error anyhow.

Comment: I solved the problem. Very embarrassing, I have accidentally overwritten the content of my model file with the routes file.